# Octave error: Gnuplot version too old (using latest 5.2)

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I have some matlab code that I'm trying to run via Octave compiler on Linux.

```
f = figure;
set(f, 'visible', 'off');
imshow(rgb_img);
hold on;
```

Where I get the following error at line 1:

> `graphics_toolkit: gnuplot version too old.`

I can confirm that my sytem is:
Octave 5.1
gnuplot 5.2
Ubuntu 18.04